# Better transition animations in premiere

Tags: premiere, animation, transitions

Let's say I want to overlay image slideshow or transition infographic over my video in Adobe Premiere. I know I can just add some *slide* or *wipe* tranistions to my assets, but those transitions look ugly, they don't have any easing or motionblur support. I also know I can animate those assets in AFX. But even with very good Premiere and AFX roundtrip support, this method still lacks crucial flexibility. For example, if I wanted to change asset display duration later, I have to either do it in AFX (and have hard time syncing it to audio for example), or go around with some freeze frame mojo basically spliting the animated asset in three parts (animation in, still frame, animation out).

I am looking for a way to handle those simple animations directly in premiere. Is there a trick or functionality I am not aware of? Or maybe some plugin? Basic functionality I am looking for is creating a slide tranistion with easing (nonlinear progress, speading up and slowing down) and maybe motionblur.

Answer (score 1):

Red Giant Universe has the support you need.

Part of the video transitions included with Universe that might be useful to you:

- Swish Pan/Slide: can create a nice slide with motion blur support and easing
- Fade In: creates sort of a zoom effect with motion blur support and
  easing.

Also has other transitions like Zoom Blur, Fold .etc. all with motion  blur support and easing.

If you are looking for some free presets I'm not sure about slide or wipe. But Chung Dha has some nice presets. They are keyframe based in Premiere, but you can modify them (but its not as drag and drop as Universe).

You can check them out here: http://www.chungdha.nl/?cat=129

Specifically the last two, namely, Smooth Transition Presets and Motion blur with transform effects.

He also has a tutorials on usability in each transition page.